# Advanced Polynomials and Rational Functions

Tags: functions, polynomials, rational-functions

Question: Given the base function: $f(x) = x^4$, describe (in point form) how each parameter of the function: $y = \frac{-1}{2}f(\frac{1}{3x} + 2)-6$ transforms the graph of $f(x)$.

I tried to do this question on my own but I found some trouble while doing it. I don't understand what a parameter is. Am I supposed to describe the translations of the graph? For example: $-1/2$ is equal to a which demonstrates a vertical stretch by a factor of $1/2$? I am very confused at the moment. I'd be thankful for anyone who can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You are to describe what each transformation on $y=f(x)=x^4$ is effected in order to give $$y=-\frac12f\left(\frac{1}{3x}+2\right)-6=-\frac12\left(\frac13\frac{1}{x}+2\right)^4-6.$$

The parameters here refer to the multipliers and the shifters (the numbers in the second expression), in addition to the transformation $x\mapsto 1/x.$

Can you at least proceed now?